# How to remove notification permission in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, notifications

There is a way to request notification permission:

```
Notification.requestPermission()
```

But is there also a way to remove the permission like:

```
Notification.removePermission()
```

Comment: Simple, you cant remove that Notification, Its a browser feature and its good that you cant remove/disable it. That would be a nightmare...

Comment: @Marc I mean that you can remove the permission to notify from your website.

Comment: Ok, i miss read that. The user has explict do remove/disallow the notifications. AFAIK there is no JS method/API to revoke the premission its once granted.